# How to convert a method into a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good afternoon, I wrote a calendar and am now trying to display events from the JSON file. I myself understand that in order to display a list with some condition, I need to use a computed property, but I can’t use it because I need to pass parameters to it, but I can’t do this. And if I use the usual method, the event rendering does not work correctly, it does not show all the events in the day, but only for one event.

For example, on the 18th, I have two events in the JSON file, but only one is displayed.

[Full code on GitHub](https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/Calendar/blob/make_events_display/src/App.vue)

```
   <template>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="overflow-div">
      <div class="pagination">
        <div @click="prevPage" class="btn-left"><</div> 
        <p>{{ nameOfOneMonth }} {{ year }}</p>
        <div @click="nextPage" class="btn-right">></div> 
      </div>

        <div class="d_nameOfDays">
          <li v-for="day in nameOfDays" class="nameOfDays">{{ day }}</li>
        </div>
        <transition :name="nameOfClass" >
          <div :key="currentPage" class="fade_wrapper">
            <div v-for="(week, i) in getCalendar" class="d_day">
            <li v-for="day in week" 
                class="li_day"
                v-bind:class="{   'currentDay': currentDayOnCalendar(i, day), }" >  
              <div class="day" 
                   v-bind:class="{  'grey': isAnotherMonth(i, day),
                                    'red': weekEndDayFunction(i, day) }">{{ day }}</div>
              <span v-for="event in buildEvents(i, day)" class="event">{{ event }}</span>
            </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div> 
</template>

<script>
  import json from './Calendar_data.json'
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      currentPage: 0,
      namesOfMonths: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      nameOfOneMonth: '',
      nameOfDays: ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'],
      date: new Date(),
      isActive: true,
      year: '',
      nameOfClass: '',
      eventsData: json,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getCalendar(){
      return this.buildCalendar();
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.year = this.date.getFullYear();
    this.currentPage = this.date.getMonth();
    this.nameOfOneMonth = this.namesOfMonths[this.currentPage];
  },
  methods: {
    isAnotherMonth(weekIndex, dayNumber) {
      if(weekIndex === 0 && dayNumber > 15) {
        // первая неделе и номер дня > 15
        return true
      }
      if (weekIndex === 4 && dayNumber < 15) {
        // последняя неделя и номер дня < 15
        return true
      }
      if (weekIndex === 5 && dayNumber < 15) {
        // последняя неделя и номер дня < 15
        return true
      }
      // день принадлежит текущему месяцу
      return false
    },
    buildEvents(weekIndex, dayNumber){
      let arrOfEvents = this.eventsData.events;
      for(let z = 0; z < arrOfEvents.length; z++){
        let dataStartOfEvent = arrOfEvents[z].starts_at;
        let getStartDataOfEvent = new Date(dataStartOfEvent);
        let dataEndOfEvent = arrOfEvents[z].ends_at;
        let getEndDataOfEvent = new Date(dataEndOfEvent);
        let memo = arrOfEvents[z].memo;
        if(getStartDataOfEvent.getDate() == getEndDataOfEvent.getDate()){
          if(dayNumber == getStartDataOfEvent.getDate() &&
            this.currentPage == getStartDataOfEvent.getMonth() &&
            this.year == getStartDataOfEvent.getFullYear() &&
            !this.isAnotherMonth(weekIndex, dayNumber)){
              return memo;
          }
        }else if(getStartDataOfEvent.getDate() != getEndDataOfEvent.getDate() &&
            !this.isAnotherMonth(weekIndex, dayNumber)){
          for(let b = getStartDataOfEvent.getDate(); b <= this.getLastDayOfMonth(getStartDataOfEvent.getMonth()); b++){
            if(dayNumber === b &&
            this.currentPage == getStartDataOfEvent.getMonth() &&
            this.year == getStartDataOfEvent.getFullYear()){
              return memo;
            }
          }
          for(let b = 0; b < getEndDataOfEvent.getDate(); b++){
            if(dayNumber === b &&
            this.currentPage == getEndDataOfEvent.getMonth() &&
            this.year == getEndDataOfEvent.getFullYear()){
               return memo
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    buildCalendar(){
      let massOfMonth = [];
      for (let months = 0; months < 12; months++){
        massOfMonth.push(months);
        massOfMonth[months] = [];
        for ( let daysInMonth = 0; daysInMonth < this.getLastDayOfMonth(months); daysInMonth++){
          massOfMonth[months].push(daysInMonth + 1)
        }
      // разбиение большого массива месяц на 
      // меньшие массивы которые имеют по 7 элементов
      var longArray = massOfMonth[this.currentPage];
      var size = 7;
      var newArray = new Array(Math.ceil(longArray.length / size)).fill("")
          .map(function() { 
            return this.splice(0, size) 
          }, longArray.slice());
       //--------------------------------------------------   
        return newArray; // вывод самого календаря
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of code, could you not strip it down to a small example that illustrates the problem? It is not really clear which method/computed property you're asking about.

Comment: Ok now i will do it

Comment: I need to convert a `buildEvents()` method into a computed property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* a computed property, you can also make some method call. Computed properties perform better if called often, because the result gets cached, but otherwise from that there is no difference to a regular method call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to pass a param to a computed property. In order to do this you need to define the computed property function to return a function with a param that you want to use.

```
computed: {
    getCalendar(){
      return myParam => {
          ...your computed property code using myParam
      }
    }
}
```